# BigQuery multiple data type in one data field

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-bigquery, schema

Is it possible to define a table schema with field that has multiple data types on it? For example:

BIGQUERY TABLE SCHEMA

```
schema: 
  [{
    name: 'field1',
    type: 'string',
  },
  {
    name: 'field2',
    type: 'string or bool',
  }]
```

Can I have a field like field2 in the example above which can have 2 datatype "String or Boolean".

Comment: no, that's not possible

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I saw many supported search db like bigquery, elasticsearch has only 1 type in 1 field, so we can not have multiple optional type in 1 field right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a struct in a field and define several data types there.

```
#standardsql
CREATE TABLE `test.table1`
(
  column1 STRUCT<
    number INT64,
    text STRING,
    truth BOOL
  >,
  column2 STRING
)
```

Technically that is one column with several data types - but in different "sub-columns":
[image: table schema]

Comment: Hi Martin Weitzmann, this is a good idea but what happen if I dont know exactly the type of input data then assign to the correct sub-columns. Suppose I call API to get data and put into bigquery, but it has 1 field that sometimes is a string, sometimes a bool value. How we deal with it

Comment: make a sub-field for every type that can show up (there's only a limited amount of data types, right) and use a conditional statement (if-else or case-when) to fill in the data to the right place.

Comment: Thank you for your instruction, I think it is the best workaround solution since it does not support multiple types yet.